# How do I use calldowns?

Tags: firefall

I know I can press C to bring up the call down menu, but what then? If I leftclick the calldown that I want to use, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>C</kbd> to open the calldowns menu, mouse down to the one you want, and left click to select it. Then press <kbd>4</kbd> to activate it, and left click to place the beacon.